# Не получается преобразовать полученнные данные из mysql в массив

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pug, koa.js

Сделал запрос в бд

```js
let user = ctx.state.user[0];
let sql = 'SELECT id_theme FROM access WHERE id_user = ?';
let themes = db.query(sql, [user.id], async (err, result) => {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    console.log(result);
    await result;
});
```

```
[ RowDataPacket { id_theme: 1 },
  RowDataPacket { id_theme: 2 },
  RowDataPacket { id_theme: 3 },
  RowDataPacket { id_theme: 2 },
  RowDataPacket { id_theme: 3 } ]
```

Только в pug я не могу его загнать

```
each theme in themes
                     p=theme
```

Как сделать так чтобы переменная themes не выводила сам запрос query к бд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model/user.js

```js
let db = require('../bin/db');
global.Promise = require('bluebird');

let User = {
    theme: function(id){
        return requestUser('SELECT id_theme FROM access WHERE id_user = ?', id);
    }
};

function requestUser(sql, req){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(
            sql,
            [req],
            (err, rows) => {
                if(err) reject(err);
                resolve(rows);
            });
    });
}

module.exports = User;
```

```js
const User = require('./model/user');

.get('/index', async ctx => {
        if(!ctx.isAuthenticated()){
            await ctx.redirect('/');
        }
        let user = ctx.state.user[0];
        let themes = await User.theme(user.id).then(theme => {
            return theme;
        });
        await ctx.render('index', {
            title: 'Главная страница',
            userBy: user,
            themes: themes,
        });
    })
```